# Insert elements in lists under array python

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-2.7, tuples

I have a array consisting of tuples.

```
Data = [('1234', 'abcd'), ('5678', 'efgh')]
```

I now have another set of variables in an array:

```
add = ["#happy", "#excited"]
```

I'm trying to append 'add' to 'Data' in the same order such that the output should look like:

```
data_new = [('1234', 'abcd', '#happy'), ('5678', 'efgh',"#excited")]
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension with `enumerate()`:

```
>>> Data = [('1234', 'abcd'), ('5678', 'efgh')]
>>> add = ['#happy', '#excited']
>>> [x + (add[i],) for i,x in enumerate(Data)]
[('1234', 'abcd', '#happy'), ('5678', 'efgh', '#excited')]
```

Note that a common pythonic way to solve this type of problem is with `zip()`, but it doesn't immediately give the desired output for your example because you end up with nested tuples:

```
>>> zip(Data,add) # or list(zip(Data,add)) in Python3
[(('1234', 'abcd'), '#happy'), (('5678', 'efgh'), '#excited')]
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Thank you Chris!

Answer (score 1):

You can add tuples in a list comprehension and use zip:

```
>>> [t+(e,) for t, e in zip(Data, add)]
[('1234', 'abcd', '#happy'), ('5678', 'efgh', '#excited')]
```

(works in Python 2 and 3)